# Camel mongodb - MongoDbProducer multiple inserts

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I am trying to do a multiple insert using the camel mongo db component.

My Pojo representation is  :

```
 Person {
 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 }
```

I have a processor which constructs a valid List of Person pojo and is a valid json structure.
When this list of Person is sent to the mongodb producer , on invocation of createDoInsert the type conversion to BasicDBObject fails. This piece of code below looks to be the problem. Should it have more fall backs / checks in place to attempt the list conversion down further below as it fails on the very first cast itself. Debugging the MongoDbProducer the exchange object being received is a DBList which extends DBObject. This causes the singleInsert flag to remain set at true which fails the insertion below as we get a DBList instead of a BasicDBObject :

```
   if(singleInsert) {
        BasicDBObject insertObjects = (BasicDBObject)insert;
        dbCol.insertOne(insertObjects);
        exchange1.getIn().setHeader("CamelMongoOid", insertObjects.get("_id"));
    }
```

The Camel MongoDbProducer code fragment

```
private Function<Exchange, Object> createDoInsert() {
    return (exchange1) -> {
        MongoCollection dbCol = this.calculateCollection(exchange1);
        boolean singleInsert = true;
        Object insert = exchange1.getIn().getBody(DBObject.class);
        if(insert == null) {
            insert = exchange1.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            if(insert == null) {
                throw new CamelMongoDbException("MongoDB operation = insert, Body is not conversible to type DBObject nor List<DBObject>");
            }

            singleInsert = false;
            insert = this.attemptConvertToList((List)insert, exchange1);
        }

        if(singleInsert) {
            BasicDBObject insertObjects = (BasicDBObject)insert;
            dbCol.insertOne(insertObjects);
            exchange1.getIn().setHeader("CamelMongoOid", insertObjects.get("_id"));
        } else {
            List insertObjects1 = (List)insert;
            dbCol.insertMany(insertObjects1);
            ArrayList objectIdentification = new ArrayList(insertObjects1.size());
            objectIdentification.addAll((Collection)insertObjects1.stream().map((insertObject) -> {
                return insertObject.get("_id");
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            exchange1.getIn().setHeader("CamelMongoOid", objectIdentification);
        }

        return insert;
    };
}
```

My route is as below :

```
    <route id="uploadFile">
    <from uri="jetty://http://0.0.0.0:9886/test"/>
    <process ref="fileProcessor"/>
    <unmarshal>
        <csv>

            <header>fname</header>
            <header>lname</header>

        </csv>

    </unmarshal>

    <process ref="mongodbProcessor" />
    <to uri="mongodb:mongoBean?database=axs175&amp;collection=insurance&amp;operation=insert" />
```

and the MongoDBProcessor constructing the List of Person Pojo

```
@Component
public class MongodbProcessor implements Processor {
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<List<String>> personlist = (ArrayList) exchange.getIn().getBody();
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<String> records : personlist){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFname(records.get(0));
        person.setLname(records.get(1));
        persons.add(person);
    }
exchange.getIn().setBody(persons);

}
}
```

Also requested information here - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problems-with-MongoDbProducer-multiple-inserts-tc5792644.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now fixed via - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10728